# Where does the Future Boy Conan movie fit in?

Tags: future-boy-conan

**Future Boy Conan** is a 26 episode TV series and a hour or so long movie. Where does the movie fit into the TV series? Is the movie a retelling of the series? Is it a side-story or a sequel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1979 movie is a [re-edited summary](http://www.nippon-animation.co.jp/work/conan_movie.html) of the 26-episode 1978 TV series.

Google translation of the above link:

> World 20 years after the world war broke out in 2008, the earth had undergone a transformation. On the island of strained island-living the grandfather and wild boy Conan, girl Lana strange day was washed ashore. Rana helped two people become friends with Conan, but it would have been taken away from the work-employee Montsouris we aim to dispatch in the world to show off the civilization of the old era of "Industria". Conan you lose your grandfather in the fight at that time, and after the island is left to follow the Rana. It is a grandson of Dr. Rao to hold the secrets of solar energy, Rana found myself being chased by administrative director Repka attempt to dominate the solar energy of the "Indus Rear". Adventure of Conan stood up to save Lana began. **Movie re-edit the TV series.**